# C++ error: cannot declare field to be of abstract type

Tags: c++

This is the situation:

```
class Base {  
    virtual void methodA() = 0;  
    virtual void methodB() = 0;  
};

class Base_A : public Base {  
    void methodA(); 
    void methodB();  
};

class Base_B : public Base {  
    void methodA();  
    void methodB();  
};

class MyClass {
    private:  
        Base * b;   
};
```

When I compile it gives the error message:

`error: cannot declare field MyClass::b to be of abstract type because the following  virtual functions are pure within Base:

    Base::methodA()

    Base::methodB()`

How to solve this?

**UPDATE**
It compiles now. I dont'know what I have changed

Comment: Is it really `Base * b;` and not `Base b;` ?

Comment: Is your code snippet correct? It actually compiles OK and is correct. Perhaps your original code had 'Base b' instead of 'Base * b'. 'Base b' would give the error you're getting.

Comment: Also..don't forget to make Base destructor virtual.

Comment: “It compiles now. I dont'know what I have changed”—Magic!

Answer (score 4):

You code seems correct and perfect .

Your Base Class is Abstract so you can't create object of it ,
but you can definately declare pointer of it.

So you might have written Base b instead of Base *b ,please check it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippets compiles fine on my computer. Are you sure that you are using `Base* b`, ie. a pointer type and not `Base b`?

Comment: I'm guessing not, since the compiler error talks about an abstract type, not a pointer.

Comment: @Jurily: Yes, Base is abstract. If you try to create a field of this type (`Base b`), the compiler will complain that one *cannot declare field MyClass::b to be of abstract type*. Pointers to abstract types are not abstract, though, and the OP's example (`Base * p`) should work.