# C++ abstract class instance in a field of another class

Tags: c++, reference, constants, abstract-class

I have the following code:

```
class Carb {
public:
    virtual void calorie() = 0; // pure virtual
}

class Omelette : Carb {
public:
    void calorie() {/*do something*/}; // non-virtual
}

class Breakfast {
public:
    Breakfast(const Carb &somecarb):
    my_carb(somecarb){}

private:
    const Carb &my_carb;
}


}
```

I understand that Carb is a virtual class therefore cannot be an instance, but we can use a pointer from the following stackoverflow questions.

[C++ : Cannot declare field to be of abstract type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296276/c-cannot-declare-field-to-be-of-abstract-type)

[C++ error: cannot declare field to be of abstract type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629925/c-error-cannot-declare-field-to-be-of-abstract-type)

However, it also seems to work by declaring a const reference like my code above. My question is, is it valid to have a class field to be a constant reference to a abstract class? Why does it work this way?

Comment: References and pointers both provide indirection; indirection is required for runtime polymorphism. Therefore, either can be used with a pure virtual class.

Comment: Just make sure the `Carb` doesn't end its lifetime before the `Breakfast`.